# Unable to display Pdf content in showing empty content android

Tags: android

```
   private void CopyReadAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "abc.pdf");
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("abc.pdf");
            out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("content://" + getFilesDir() + "/sample.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

in manifest file :

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

This is my code ii am trying to display a pdf file in the application from assets folder when I try to open its opening but it is empty showing there is no content display. please help me with what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `This is my code ii am trying to display a pdf file in the application from assets folder`. That assets folder is irrelevant at that moment. You are trying to display a file from getFilesDir().

Comment: And you should use FileProvider to get a nice uri. Now you are building up a very invalid one yourself.

Comment: after the change that I am getting      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 11024 does not have permission to content://com.example.fireex.fileprovider/external_files/pdfFiles/sample.pdf [user 0]